# Eclipse: how to change current word background color?

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-cdt, background-color

I set Eclipse in dark mode. Everything is fine, except the word where the cursor is currently located. This is shown with a light foreground color on a light grey background. Almost unreadable.

I could not fine the option to change this setting.

Language: C++
Version: Eclipse 2019-12

Comment: What release of Eclipse? Which editor (what type of file)? The basic text editor does not do this in dark mode (current Eclipse 2019-12).

Comment: @greg-449 - Just added the details you asked for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a [known issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551941).

You should be able to change the color under Preferences --> General --> Editors --> Text Editors --> Annotations --> C/C++ Occurrences.